# How to take elements from range with lambda expressions and linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I take elements by range with lambda and linq?

For example:

I have a table with 54 elements. I just want to take elements from possition 1-10, or 10-20 or 20-30 etc - generally by some numeric range.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
IEnumerable<int> interval = list.Skip(a).Take(b);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Enumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) methods;

> Bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns
>   the remaining elements.

---

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

```
List<int> yourlist = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
IEnumerable<int> newlist = yourlist.Skip(2).Take(3);

foreach(var i in newlist)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Output will be;

```
3
4
5
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/HZNzla).

Answer (score 4):

if what you want is pageing,

```
int pageIndex = 1;
int pageSize= 10

List<object> list = new List<object>();
IEnumerable<object> interval = list.Skip(pageIndex*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
MyList.Skip(x).Take(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.Skip(n1).Take(n2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<T>.GetRange(int index, int count);`

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> firstThreeNumbers = numbers.GetRange(0, 3);
List<int> lastThreeNumbers = numbers.GetRange(numbers.Count - 3, 3);
```

Don't `Skip` and `Take`, just `GetRange`!

Hope this helps!