# .NET CF - DataGrid.DataSource - Get value using row no and property/column name

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagrid, compact-framework

Using the .NET Compact Framework (3.5) you can set DataGrid.DataSource to a number of different types of object such as DataTable, IList, IEnumerable etc.

Is there a way to get a value of a Row and Property/Column Name for the data source?

For example a method like

```
Function GetValue(rowIndex As Integer, memberPath As String) As Object
```

This would need to work on the DataSource (regardless of type) prior to the table/column styles being setup.

Answer (score 0):

The code below returns an object:

```
dtgBuscaProduto.DataSource = IEnumerableProduct.ToList();
var value = dtgBuscaProduto[row, column];
```

Comment: Assuming dtgBuscaProduto is a datatable, this would not work if the datasource is an IEnumerable(of T)

Comment: No, dtgBuscaProduto is a DataGrid. In my case, I cast the IEnumerable to List in Data Source. Code updated.

Comment: This does not appear to be valid for .NET CF (3.5)

Comment: I am using .NET CF (3.5) with SDK windows Mobile 6.0

Comment: My mistake, however this only works once the table/column styles have been setup and with the column index. If I wanted to get the value by item and member name (e.g. row=1, member=Price) this is not suitable.
The only way i can see to do this is to check the type and use reflection for IEnumerables and cast data tabels/sets.

Comment: In this case I don't know where DataGrid impact on this. You need use skip and take lambda functions. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790641/how-to-take-elements-from-range-with-lambda-expressions-and-linq)